# Data Designer limitations and SFMC processing time

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-designer, attribute-group

There's a curious situation with a SFMC instance that has a fairly complex architecture and massive amounts of data in a single BU, that apparently is too much for Marketing Cloud to handle.

- There are approximately **45** Attribute Groups each with approximately **15-20** DE links.
- The DE's have between **5-30M** records each.

Having this setup in one Business Unit is causing issues on multiple levels, such as Journey Builder contacts processing time is incredibly slow and working in Data Designer is up to your luck, in most cases it freezes for a good while.

Salesforce Product Team even stated that this single BU is taking up so much processing power that it has started to affect *other* SFMC instances on the server stack and so they had to de-prioritize the performance levels for this single BU in order to maintain balance.

In documentation there is no official word on the amount of min/max Attribute Groups, nor are there any comments about performance when it comes to Data Designer in general. Sure, there is the recommended limit related to Populations (3-5) but that's it.

Has anyone ran into similar issue? Or is there an unofficial documentation for some limits to check?

Comment: Why does everything have to be in Data Designer?  Also, it's probably classified as a high-risk architecture and I'm surprised it didn't start with a dedicated database instance.

Comment: Actually we do have dedicated DB as well, so the fact that it still affects other instances is super strange. It's all in Data Designer due to the way this client has split their database, no real way around it - aside from splitting it all to multiple BU's.